# UIImageView not showing Image

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have the following code:

```
@interface NeighborProfileViewController : UIViewController {
    UIImageView * profPic;
    UITextView * text;
    UIButton * buzz;
    NSString * uid;
    NSMutableData *responseData;
    NSDictionary * results;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView * profPic;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView * text;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton * buzz;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * uid;

@end
```

Here's what I have in the `viewDidLoad` on the `.m` file

```
@implementation NeighborProfileViewController
@synthesize uid;
@synthesize profPic;
@synthesize buzz;
@synthesize text;


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url = //some URL to the picture;
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *img = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data] autorelease];
    self.profPic = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: img];
}
```

I think I wired up the `UIImageView` via `IB` correctly. I have an outlet from the `UIImageView` to the profPic in the Files Owner. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are setting a default image is that staying visible after you call `self.profPic = [UIImageView]` or is it being removed from the screen?
I think this problem comes when `self.profPic` releases the old image view to replace it with the one you've just created. The old `UIImageView` instance, along with all the properties which you defined in IB, are probably automatically removed from the superview. Which is why you're not seeing the downloaded image.

If you used `IB` to create the `UIImageView` then you don't want to create a new ImageView and assign it to `profPic` (which is already a fully instantiated `UIImageView`). Try calling `[profPic setImage:img];` which will just change the image in the `profPic` imageview.

Comment: Was beating my head around this for couple of hours. was allocating the imageview again before setting the image. Thanks @thelaws

Answer (score 2):

@Equinox use

```
  [profPic setImage:img];
```

instead of

```
self.profPic = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: img];
```

although using autorelease is not an issue here.
you can also do something like this

```
  UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data] ;
  [profPic setImage:img];
  [img release];
```

the problem with

```
self.profPic = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: img];
```

is that you are now creating another memory location for profPic and that means profPic will no longer point to the UIImageView in your IB any more